# Console.WriteLine sometimes throws the handle is invalid exception

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-functions, console

I have an Azure function which has this line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + list.Count());
```

This line sometimes throws this exception:

> The handle is invalid.
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:352)
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:108)
> Inner exception System.IO.IOException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
> at System.ConsolePal+WindowsConsoleStream.Write (System.Console, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.WriteLine (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.IO.TextWriter+SyncTextWriter.WriteLine (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
> at System.Console.WriteLine (System.Console, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

Should we ignore this or don't use console class in Azure function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when the console window has been closed, or if the console output has been redirected to a file or other stream.

In azure functions, you should not use the `Console.WriteLine`. instead, you should use `ILogger`  to write logs. you can write logs like `log.LogInformation("Name: " + list.Count());`, this will write output to the Azure Functions runtime log. you can also view logs in the azure portal.

**Edit**: As @Fildor suggested in comment, you could use `log.LogInformation("Name: {count}", list.Count());`

Comment: This. I would recommend semantic logging, though.

Comment: @Fildor thank you for your comment, but I have very limited azure knowledge, please add more details in comment or add as your answer

Comment: Nothing big. Just prefer `log.LogInformation("Name: {count}", list.Count());`

Comment: @Fildor thank you got it. I will modify my answer